# Can I use LED on the actual RS485 bus?

Tags: pcb-design, rs485

How bad of an idea is to put a LED on the actual RS485 bus AB lines, for indication of activity on the bus. Something like this:[image]

I know people would say why not put LED on 'Recieve' and 'Drive' pins instead, well because I don't wanna. It adds to many components where there is not a lot of space on the board. The LED just next to the termination resistor seems very convinent.

EDIT: I am using SN75176B as the driver

Comment: The usual way to do this is to hook up the signal lines to a transistor that drives the LED, because you don't want to be pulling multiple mA on your signal lines.

Comment: As with any similar hack where you do something outside the standard design space, context is key. It would b helpful to clarify your question by adding details such as the intended LED current, bus length, speed, whether you're always using a specific driver that might exceed RS485 standards or need to handle any driver on the bus, safety criticality, etc.

Comment: I see your point, but what if the forward current is only 5-10mA on the LED? and there is only one node connecting at the end of the bus?

Comment: 5-10 mA is a lot for a signal line.

Comment: Oh, and this will also completely screw up your termination.

Comment: @nanofarad Yes my bad, length is hardly 10-20cm speed is 1mbps. I am using 75176 as the RS485 driver.

Comment: @Hearth I see, I thought since the driver is rated for 60mA. 5mA shouldn't hurt, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Bubu Depends on the driver, really. It might work, it might destroy your signal quality, it might burn out your driver.

Comment: The differential voltage across the AB swings between -V and +V (e.g. -5V and +5V). The negative voltage can harm your LED. Most 3mm red LEDs have a reverse voltage rating of 5V, for example.

Comment: If data rate is 1 Mbps, do you think the LED would blink too fast to be anything else than a dim blip? I mean, whether or not it is a good idea depends on why are you doing this and under what assumptions. For example, for debugging a non-working DMX-512 system, you would connect LEDs to RS-485 bus just for the purpose of finding the fault and then disconnect them after bus is fixed. Having LEDs permanently connected may not be a good idea in general, but for limited purpose it might be OK. What is the purpose? Do you only transmit? Are all devices 5V? Do you always terminate bus?

Comment: @Justme It goes on a development board that needs constantly developing the firmware. Connecting and Disconnecting the testing equipment is too much of a hassle. For me a dim blimp is fine and good indication of working system. I just want to know how bad would it degrade the signal quality?

Comment: I think with a large value resistor (so very little current) you could probably do this without seriously impacting signal. Try 10kohm.

Comment: @Bubu "How bad it would degrade the signal" is impossible to answer without information of the whole system, including the LED and the resistor for it. Depending on the LED and load on fully terminated bus, there might not be enough voltage to light up a LED.

Comment: The LED in series with that resistor, no matter what the value, is not a proper parallel (destination) termination scheme for RS-485.

Comment: @Justme I see thanks for your insight. I am thinking maybe this was a stupid idea all along.

Comment: @SteveSh Yes I see my error now. I should have put the LED in parallel to the termination resistor not in series with it, along with its own current limiting resistor.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely going to ruin the termination.

The differential voltage on an RS485 bus is at least 1.5V which is around the voltage drop of your LED. This makes it makes it almost impossible for you to control the current flowing through your LED. However, you have a bigger problem with the termination resistance (and signal integrity).

The termination resistance seen is $$ R_{termination} = \frac{U}{I}$$ with U being the voltage level of the differential signal and $$ I = \frac{U-U_{LED}}{R_{LED}}) $$. Therefore, the termination resistance seen is $$ R_{termination} = \frac{U}{I} = \frac{UR_{LED}}{U-U_{LED}}$$. In other words, the termination resistance is dependant on the differential voltage U.
This might not be a problem if the same RS485 tranceiver is used everywhere. But as soon as there are differnt tranceivers with different voltages on the bus we have different termination resistances.

Your design might or might not work depending, among other factors, on the bus length and speed. I recommend you to add a RS485 receiver to the bus and connect the LED to it. This makes sure there is no adverse effect on the signal integrity.